# Java input not being accepted by readline

Tags: java, variables, input, bufferedreader, readline

I'm trying to store a bunch of variables through bufferedreader. I'm brand new to Java and frankly don't really understand completely what it even does, but I know that it accepts input from the user and am trying to get it to store a bunch of variables for me. Here is the code:

```
// import required packages for the program, importing all classes from packages to be on the safe side
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class Example
{
// need to use throws IO Exception because we are dealing with input and output, simple main method will not suffice
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    // declare department names as strings
    String department1;
    String department2;
    String department3;
    String department4;

    // declare number of employees in each department as ints
    int employees1;
    int employees2;
    int employees3;
    int employees4;

    // declare cost per employee in each department as doubles
    double cpe1;
    double cpe2;
    double cpe3;
    double cpe4;

    //declare sales in each department as doubles
    double sales1;
    double sales2;
    double sales3;
    double sales4;

    // declare in as a BufferedReader- used to gain input from the user
    BufferedReader in;
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    //get input from the user to define department names
    System.out.println("What is the name of department 1?");
    department1 = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("What is the name of department 2?");
    department2 = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("What is the name of department 3?");
    department3 = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("What is the name of department 4?");
    department4 = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("\n");

    //get input fromm the user to define number of employees
    System.out.println("How many employees are in department 1?");
    employees1 = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("How many employees are in department 2?");
    employees2 = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("How many employees are in department 3?");
    employees3 = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("How many employees are in department 4?");
    employees4 = in.readLine();
    System.out.printlin("\n");

    // get input from user to define cost per employee in each department
    System.out.println("What is the cost per employee in department 1?");
    cpe1 = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("What is the cost per employee in department 2?");
    cpe2 = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("What is the cost per employee in department 3?");
    cpe3 = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("What is the cost per employee in department 4?");
    cpe4 = in.readLine();

    // get input from user to define sales in each department
    System.out.println("What are the sales in department 1?");
    sales1 = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("What are the sales in department 2?");
    sales2 = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("What are the sales in department 3?");
    sales3 = in.readLine();
    System.out.println("What are the sales in department 4?");
    sales4 = in.readLine();
```

I keep getting an error saying that incompatible types are occurring when I try and run the program. Again, very new to this so a any simple explanations would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the detailed stack trace and input you are using?

Comment: Thank you for asking a good question. I don't know enough about Java to help you, but we appreciate that you asked a real question and not just a "give-me-teh-codez" type thing. +1

Comment: I suggest you use a `java.util.Scanner`, it has several helpful methods (like `nextDouble()`).

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what this means? I'm running the program in the command line on windows if that helps at all.

Comment: readLine always only reads strings.  If you want to use it for numeric input, you'll need to `Parse` the values out of the strings.  Otherwise, I think `Scanner` is what the cool kids are using to read console input these days.  The cool kids who use it almost always forget that they have to scan for the carriage returns too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `readLine` method returns `String`.
This code will not even compile.
If you want to get an `int` value, you need to call for example `Integer.parseInt(ln)`,
where `ln` is the line you read from the input. Analogically, if you want to get a `double` value, you need to call for example `Double.parseDouble(ln)`,
where `ln` is the line you read from the input.

Comment: Thank you for this. But in order to get the input to turn the number into an integer, musn't they first be declared as strings so that readLine can get the input in the first place?

Comment: @Zack No, you can just do it on the fly like this: employees1 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine()); where employees1 is declared as int.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is one of type; you have several different data-types present, but you only read Strings. I would use a `java.util.Scanner` like so -

```
java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What is the name of department 1?");
if (in.hasNextLine()) {
  department1 = in.nextLine();
}
// ...
System.out.println("How many employees are in department 1?");
if (in.hasNextInt()) {
    employees1 = in.nextInt();
}
// ...
System.out.println("What is the cost per employee in department 1?");
if (in.hasNextDouble()) {
  cpe1 = in.nextDouble();
}
```

Comment: truthfully this seems more advanced than what I've learned thus far in my course. I'm just trying to get the grasp of input/output at the moment. Would it be possible to achieve what I am trying to do through declaring all the variables as strings and then doing something like: i = Integer.valueOf(s).intValue(); ?

Comment: @Zack read peter.petrov he explained how to fix your code without use Scanner or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Scanner Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) This should do a lot of what you need. It allows you to read in inputs as Integers/Strings/Doubles, without having to do any manual conversion

Answer (score 0):

`in.readLine()` yields a String - not automatically convertible to int or double. Consider `Integer.parseInt(string)`.

Answer (score 0):

The readLine() method returns a String. You're trying to store that String in int and double variables. There are methods in the wrapper classes (like Integer and Double) for converting from a String to a number.

You might also consider using the Scanner class instead.